# lua redis string comparison not working

Tags: nginx, lua, redis, string-comparison, openresty

```
local password = json_string["password"] or "None"
local redisPassword = red:hmget(userName,"password") or None
local redisAuthtoken = red:hmget(userName,"authToken")
if (tostring(password)   ==  tostring(redisPassword))
then
    ngx.say(redisAuthtoken) 
else
    ngx.say("Error User or Service Not found 1510")
end
```

password = admin
redisPassword = admin

i am able to see both password as output admin but it is not matching in lua code and control always going to else part.

when i am comparing like this

if (tostring(password)   ==  "admin" )

it is working fine which means the issue is with the redis value but i have set password value admin in redis.

Comment: What does the variable `None` contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that `hmget` returns `multi-bulk reply`, which has the result in a lua table, so you should probably do something like this:

```
local res, err = red:hmget(userName,"password")
local redisPassword
if res and res ~= ngx.null then redisPassword = res[1] end
ngx.say(redisPassword)
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#methods):

> A non-nil Redis "multi-bulk reply" results in a Lua table holding all the composing values (if any). If any of the composing value is a valid redis error value, then it will be a two element table {false, err}. A nil multi-bulk reply returns in a ngx.null value.

Note that `ngx.null` value is not the same as Lua `nil` value, so you may need to check for that separately.

Also note that you use `None` as a variable and `"None"` as a string in two different places, which may not do what you expect.

Comment: Awsome thanx @Paul